# Hosting a Craft install in a subfolder of a Wordpress site on Windows IIS

Tags: windows, subfolder

Alright, I know the question is kind of a doozy but I'm running out of options.

I've uploaded my Craft install to the subdirectory `website.com/travel` and left in the base `web.config` that comes with Craft:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?p={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've also moved the `Craft/` directory right next to `travel/`'s `index.php`.

Visiting `website.com/travel/about` takes me to Wordpress' `404`, however `website.com/travel/index.php/about` takes me to the correct page.

However, visiting the cp at `website.com/travel/index.php/admin` removes `index.php` from the url (but still gives me a Wordpress `404`).

I've also tried `/index.php/` and `/index.php?p=` but both results are the same.

I'm not very well-versed in IIS or web.config settings, so I've just been trying things randomly to no avail. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Does Wordpress have its own `web.config` in the parent folder?  `web.config` files are just like `.htaccess` files in that they inherit rules from their parent files.

Comment: It does, but I also disabled inheritance, so it's not governed by the parent directory.

Comment: Shot in the blind, but have you tried adding the subdirectory to the rewrite, like `<action type="Rewrite" url="travel/index.php?p={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />`? Might also try only matching whatever is after `travel` in the url with something like `<match url="^travel/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />`

Comment: Thanks for the response @megatrond. It turns out this was a server config issue (not on my end at all). The sys admin did something on the windows and then it started to work. I will try and follow up with my contractor to see if I can get an adequate answer to respond to my original question.

Comment: Would leave to hear the results, @RobErskine!